# Best practice with mysql innodb to rename huge table when table with same name already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance, sqlperformance

I Use Mysql 5.5..  + INNODB and windows server.

The case(make it simple then real case):

I have 2 tables 1GB with name `new_car` and `car` table 1GB.

I to replace `car` table with `new_car` table every 10 hours not manually(auto by code) - important to do it fast(real website data).

I read(say that drop its problem in innodb) :http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/03/performance-problem-with-innodb-and-drop-table/

solution1:

```
DROP TABLE car;
RENAME TABLE new_car TO car;
```

Solution2(making drop in the end -maybe it not block the table to access that happen during drop):

```
RENAME TABLE car TO temp_car;
RENAME TABLE new_car TO car;
DROP TABLE temp_car;
```

Solution3(Truncate delete fast the table and create empty table then maybe drop action after should be very fast):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE car;
DROP TABLE car;
RENAME TABLE new_car TO car;
```

Solution4:

```
RENAME TABLE car TO temp_car;
RENAME TABLE new_car TO car;
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_car;
DROP TABLE temp_car;
```

Which solution is the best and why or please write other better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Set up a development and test environment and test it.

Comment: [See in this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) we could alter the table name seems. Have a backup copy before doing any.

Comment: i read the link above before i ask the question, thanks

Comment: Solution 2 looks good. Go for it. Even better, leave temp_car for a while in case you need to go back.

Comment: Ben, what about solution4?(the process done auto by code every 10 hours and not manually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you would DROP the table. You always want those 2 tables and you'd (I'd assume be refilling up the New_Car table...

```
RENAME TABLE car TO temp_car;
RENAME TABLE new_car TO car;
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_car;
RENAME TABLE temp_car TO new_car;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RENAME TABLE car TO temp_car, new_car TO car;
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_car;
DROP TABLE temp_car;
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [RENAME TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html) documentations:

> RENAME TABLE renames one or more tables. Renaming operations are performed left to right.

Instead of running multiple queries for rename, you can do multiple table renames in a single query like this:

```
RENAME TABLE car TO temp_car, new_car TO car
DROP TABLE temp_car
```

Although please be aware that such a table rename might cause locking/latency issues for several seconds. It depends on your application if that is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Use replace into It takes like 5 min
or 
Use Load infile to bulk it